# how to update a single row in a table for wizard type interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am facing a problem where I have one giant database table and I will have to insert data for a wizard type interface. The wizard has close to 9 steps to complete.

[image]

the requirement is,  I will have to update one single row for every step. I can't create a new row. But, I am wondering how can I achieve such functionality without destroying the data of previous steps?

I am using asp.net core 3.1 and MVC with razor view. Entity Framework is used for database operation

Comment: What do you mean by without destroying the data? if you are updating the same column(s) in every step, then previous values will be overridden right?

Comment: @RajeshG it is wizard type interface. I will need to save parts of data in to single row but different columns of a table

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:
1. You can use javascript wizards where all inputs are stored in single form.
2. You can send current page data to controller with step number and pass to new page in ViewBag until last step. In last step, store it in database.
3. Update database row in every step. This is not recommended. Because it will create many database requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my client wants the third options.

Answer (score 0):

For third option do followings:

1. Create db model with nullable parameters.

   2. Create controller action which takes db model as post parameter and step of wizard az route parameter.
   3. Inside action do switch case for each step.
   4. In step 1. Use dbcontext.model.add(formmodel);
   5. In next steps do this: dbcontext.database.executerawsql("UPDATE model_name SET parameters to be changed in the step", pass parameters with sqlparameter);

Update statement is for SQL Server, but you can update according to your database provider.